# Representations of Calkin algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a  separable Hilbert space and consider the Calkin algebra $C(H)=\frac{B(H)}{K(H)}$.

Q) True or false: Any representation of $C(H)$ is a direct sum of irreducible representations.

Comment: I think the correct spelling is "Calkin".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you google "representations of the Calkin algebra", you find the 1967 paper of Sakai which answers your question in the negative: It says that the Calkin algebra has a type III factor representation. By the Lemma of Schur, however, every irrducible representation is a type I representation and a direct sum of more than one irreducible is not a factor.

Comment: Thank a lot. Hence the second dual of Calkin algebra should be a very complicated von Neumann algebra. Is there any paper in which I find something  concerning the second dual of Calkin algebra?!